# Digispark code not uploading to arduino. Error message being displayed

Tags: arduino

Trying to upload code to a DigiSpark USB in Arduino, but I keep getting this error...

Arduino: 1.8.19 (Mac OS X), Board: "Digispark (Default - 16.5mhz)"

fork/exec /Users/dhibbert/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++: bad CPU type in executable
Error compiling for board Digispark (Default - 16.5mhz).

Answer (score 4):

AVR is using an executable that is incompatible with your processor but we can trick it by linking to one that works. Run the following commands:

```
cd ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc
mv 4.8.1-arduino5 old_4.8.1
ln -s /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr 4.8.1-arduino5
```