# Arduino IDE not compiling Digispark

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am attempting to upload a script onto my Digispark ATTINY85. I have installed all the correct packages on Arduino IDE. However when I try upload the script, I get this error:

```
Compilation error: fork/exec /Users/me/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++: bad CPU type in executable
```

**I am running on macOS Monterey 12.2.1 with Apple M1.**

I have tried following this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72550638/digispark-code-not-uploading-to-arduino-error-message-being-displayed), however then I am left with the following error:

```
bin/avr-g++: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was able to fix it like this:

1. Delete / uninstall all previous Digispark boards
2. In the Arduino IDE under *Preferences > Additional boards manager URLs* replace the original digistump URL with        `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArminJo/DigistumpArduino/master/package_digistump_index.json`
3. Reinstall the Digistump AVR Boards via *Tools > Boards Manager*. At this point I was able to compile the sketch, but not to upload it.
4. I had to downgrade to 1.7.2. Download the files from [here](https://github.com/ArminJo/DigistumpArduino/releases/tag/1.7.2).
5. Open `~/Library/Arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr` delete the content and insert the unpacked files from **digistump-avr-1.7.1.zip**
6. Go to `~/Library/Arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus` and create a folder with the name **2.5** if it does not exist yet. Delete everything else.
7. Go to the files that you downloaded and unpack `/tools/micronucleus-cli-2.5-x86_64-apple-darwin.tar.gz` it should create a new folder ***micronucleus***